# Distributing Private apps in Google Play Store for specific Google accounts

Tags: android, google-play

I am making an android app which I want to distribute to Play Store from my Developer Account and make it available for just 5-10 specific google accounts. I read Google Plays support page for releasing private apps (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6145139?hl=en). What I understand from reading this article, is that to release an app for Private distribution, the users must belong to an organization. I assume this means the users must belong to a Gsuite Subscription.

Instead of it, is there a way to distribute an app privately where I can make it available to just specific google accounts which I can modify anytime I want and the users don't need to pay  for Gsuite Subscription. The users also need to be able to use the app for extended periods of time.

I know there's an easier way to distribute the app with APK file, but that creates the hassle of checking "Install from Unknown sources" from user's phone. Also for each subsequent update the APK file needs to be distributed repeatedly to each individual user.